# Set iframe URL from code behind

Tags: web-part, iframe

We have a SharePoint site, where we want to load an `iframe`. Now our problem is, that the `iframe` needs to have a dynamic URL. How can we achieve that?

At the moment we are using an `EventReceiver` which generates a webpart.

To add some more details, we generate the webpart in an `EventReceiver` what we want to achieve is, that we modify the `iframe`'s `src`-attribute on every request to the webpart.

The `EventReceiver` is of type `SPFeatureReceiver` and here is some code:

```
   public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
   {
   var web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

   if (!PageUtil.PageExists(web, "somepage.aspx"))
   {
       PageUtil.AddWebpartPage(web, "Service Portal", "somepage.aspx");
   }

   // Add site viewer webpart
   PageViewerWebPart webPart = new PageViewerWebPart();

   if (!PageUtil.WebpartExists(web, webPart, string.Format("{0}/{1}", "SitePages", "somepage.aspx")))
   {
       webPart.ContentLink = "contenturl";
       webPart.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;
       PageUtil.AddWebpartToPage(web, webPart, "SitePages/somepage.aspx", "main", 0);
   }
   }
```

Comment: Eventreceivers are async,i donot think u can achive this in eventreceiver, try a different way or please elaborate more about your scenario

Comment: @Shiva I added some details

Comment: Can't you use Client Side Object model in that case? It will be much more easier and implement and maintain.

Comment: @AmalHashim sadly no, because we need to have the src set before the page is rendered.

Comment: @AmalHashim I added some code.